# Unwanted space between two ImageView on android

Tags: android, imageview, padding, margin, android-linearlayout

Im using this Layout to put two ImageViews one next to the other, but the two images seems to be separated by 1 transparent pixel space.
The blue background is there to make easier to observe the problem...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0000FF">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/i_position_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/i_position_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The .java is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
}
```

Im using a device with android 2.2.
I wasnt able to reproduce the glitch on a 2.1-update1 emulator neither on a 1.6 emulator... 
Ive checked the images and they have no extra pixels arround them.
Also i tried adding a red 1px width border on the images separately and the glitch is still there, so the images dont seem to be the problem.
These are the problematic images (correctly shown here):
[image: Image A][image: Image B]
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7024937/i_position_icon.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7024937/i_position_seekbar.png

And this is what i see in my device:
[image: Transparent pixel between ImageViews]

Thanks.

Comment: Please let us know your SDK version.

Comment: Im using a device with android 2.2. I wasnt able to reproduce the glitch on a 2.1-update1 emulator neither on a 1.6 emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds strange because I use the same technique in my project and everything seems to be OK. Do you put your drawables into the correct drawable folder. I mean that you should put your images in drawable-hdpi folder if your device has hdpi screen. Sorry, but it's the only thought that came into my mind.

Comment: Thanks, but the resources already are in drawable-hdpi.
Im developing on a galaxy i900b. Have you tried with the images i uploaded to dropbox? Because i dont have the issue with other images...

Comment: Ive just sorted the issue.
Making the bigger image 1 pixel longer on its left.
Its really anoying because i still dont know why is this happening.
Now the two images sum 457px when the phone can display 480px without stretching. Ill try to test the code in another device.

Comment: I've just tried it on all devices I have and on the emulator and haven't noticed any problems.

Comment: Just figured out the problem. Seems that netbeans refused to really "clean" the project after rebuild. The problem was solved deleting by hand the contents of build and dist folders. Thanks a lot! Making this the accepted answer for the problems hehe.

Answer (score 0):

strange, what version SDK are you targeting? i copied your layout and code and made a new project with api level 3 (1.5) and tested it on a 1.5 and 2.2 emulator. On both it worked fine without any spacing.

Comment: Im using a device with android 2.2. As you, i wasnt able to reproduce the glitch on a 2.1-update1 emulator neither on a 1.6 emulator.